# Sort Column Group in SSRS Matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014

I created a report using matrix and I want to add interactive sort for it's column group. When I add interactive sort for `Sales Amount` it does not work.

This is my first look of my report:

[image]

and when I click on sort arrows it turn to this one:

[image]

nothing happened an the value of Australia changed!!!

But I do it with Table and it works good.

How I can sort such these columns in column groups in matrix?

thanks

Comment: could you provide some example data in a table? i think i could help you if you had any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to recreate your scenario in order to reproduce your issue. First I created a tablix with this columns and groups.

[image]

For interactive sorting I selected the `Sales` column header, right clicked went to `Text box Properties...` and set this settings in the `Interactive Sorting` tab.

[image]

This will sort `Countries` based on the sales sum while `Sales Territories` keep the
same. If you want to order the `Sales Territories` just select that group name in the `Groups` option.

[image]

This is a test:

[image]

Use this step-by-step guide, if the Australia sales value keeps changing try deploying the report to a server, I've encountered cases when VS viwer doesn't handle applied JavaScript correctly. Also consider sharing your data in order to check if the issue is related to it.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort at the group Level. This would be the Row GroupName.
Sort by would be the SUM(SalesAmount)
And you would apply that sorting to all groups within the entire dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wasting your time trying to get Interactive Sorting to do that.  The feature is too primitive for your scenario.

Instead I would add a Report Parameter to control the sort, and use it to drive Sort By Expressions which you can control at each Group level.

The user experience is less interactive, but it actually works.